# How can I loop through many ComboBoxes with similar name?

Tags: c#

I have many ComboBoxes with similar name like ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3 and etc. How can I looping through these ComboBoxes and get some parameters of them.
In VB.NET it's like that:

```vb
For k As Integer = 1 To 50
    Console.WriteLine(Me.GroupBox1.Controls("ComboBox" & k).SelectedIndex)
Next
```

Can I do something like that on C#?

Comment: No, this will not work. While you can use FindControl to look for the Name property this is not even a unique string. Best collect them in a List<Combobox> and loop over the list. You can try to collect by looping over the Controls collection if they have a common Parent..

Comment: `In VB.NET it's like that:` - you can do [exactly the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Item_System_String_) in C#. Not that it was a good way to do it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_) method

```
        for (int k = 0; k < 50; i++)
        {
            Control[] arr = this.GroupBox1.Controls.Find("ComboBox" + k, true);
            if(arr.Length > 0)
            {
                ComboBox cb = arr[0] as ComboBox;
                Console.WriteLine(cb.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code does a different thing to the original VB code, and in the most inefficient way too.